# Android: Draw bezier curved shape

Tags: android, view, shapes, bezier

I'm trying to draw shape with a top shadow like in the picture (curve at start, bezier curve at center and curve at the end):

[image: What i want to achieve]

Currently i have done only bezier curve at the center and shadow for it using custom view class and drawing.
Current look:

[image: Current look]

Questions:

1. Why shadow only shown on central curve, not in whole shape?
2. How i can add additional curves at start and end?

Thanks!

Layout:

```
<com.example.CurvedBottomNavigationShadowView
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
```

Class:

```
public class CurvedBottomNavigationShadowView extends View {
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;

    public final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 65;
    public final int CURVE_PARAM1 = 70;
    public final int CURVE_START_PARAM = 15;

    public Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();

    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal")
    public Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    public int mNavigationBarWidth;
    public int mNavigationBarHeight;

    public CurvedBottomNavigationShadowView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationShadowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CurvedBottomNavigationShadowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        mPaint.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_START_PARAM, 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 2));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_START_PARAM, 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS - CURVE_PARAM1, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + CURVE_PARAM1, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);

        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

**Update 1.** Added a padding as according in comments. Shadow drawn correctly.
[image: Working shadow variant]

Comment: 1. To get a curved path at the end, maybe you can use `quadTo` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12716461/891373
2. For the shadow, it could be related to the padding available in the view to draw the shadow.

Comment: Your element doesn't have enough space to showing shadow (while has shadow), You have to set margin (or padding)

Comment: @Froyo Thanks! How i can set padding? I tried using setPadding inside class but it's not working at all.

Comment: `mPath.moveTo(0, 0);` - here try setting height as 5, or 10 to test whether it works or not. You would also need to change how you calculate height to account for top padding.